# Common Web View in Flutter web

Tags: flutter

I have a common header widget throughout my web app. Now what I'm doing is I am creating a common web view with the headers and child and whatever page I want to show. What I want is, I don't want to call common web view each time while navigating to a new page and creating new instance, instead can I have it only once and only the inner child page changes everytime?

Is it possible in flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

In order to present whole app in one web view you need to handle navigation delegate in webview alike amazone and flipkart

```
..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            debugPrint('''
Page resource error:
  code: ${error.errorCode}
  description: ${error.description}
  errorType: ${error.errorType}
  isForMainFrame: ${error.isForMainFrame}
          ''');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              debugPrint('blocking navigation to ${request.url}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            debugPrint('allowing navigation to ${request.url}');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) {
            debugPrint('url change to ${change.url}');
          },
        ),
      )
```

You can take a look at the whole example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example).

Comment: this package won't work for web right? I have exactly what amazon has a header, so when navigating to new page I don't want to call the headers again, only the inner page and url should change

Comment: Yes, this package is for Android and IOS platform.

Comment: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/main/ANDROID_SETUP.md     If in debug mode you should get this type of notification when background task is getting executed, can you check it ?

Comment: yes was getting it in mobile